# Ask good questions and get an Inquistive badge

Tags: discussion, site-activity, badges

In order to get out of beta, our site must consistently get 10 new questions per day. According to my own measures (for the last 11 months), we have gotten between 0.4 and 1.4 questions per day, and most of the time, we were at 0.7 or lower.

StackExchange has badges for people who ask many good questions:

- the [Curious badge](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/curious) is awarded to people who "ask a well-received question on **5** separate days, and maintain a positive question record." At the time of writing, this badge has been awarded 11 times.
- The [Inquisitive badge](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/badges/88/inquisitive) is awarded to people who "ask a well-received question on **30** separate days, and maintain a positive question record." At the time of writing, this badge has been awarded only once.
- The [Socratic badge](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/socratic) is awarded to people who "ask a well-received question on **100** separate days, and maintain a positive question record."

I will create one answer to this question, namely one with a lists of the **first ten people on our site who get an Inquisitive badge**. (An answer for the Socratic badge can be added later, as soon as someone gets that badge.)

Answer (score 2):

### First Ten to a Get an Inquisitive Badge

1. Christophe Strobbe (1 January 2017)
2. [AML](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/4939/aml) (28 September 2018)
3. ?
4. ?
5. ?
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?